# PostgreSQL - query the value for Nth instance of key in JSONB data

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Sorry for the formatting on this. There's too much text to create a readable table, so bear with me.

I have a table called 'declines'. It has two columns: 'id' and 'dec_reasons'.

For id = 34254, this is the 'dec_reasons' value in JSONB format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 94748,
        "reason": "Lead Fico Threshold is not Greater Than Or Equal To 500",
        "created_at": "2019-05-02T07:57:59.706448",
        "decline_code": "fico_too_low",
        "leaf_node_id": 7,
        "decision_type": "credit",
        "triggers_noaa": true,
        "general_description": "FICO score is too low"
    },
    {
        "id": 94747,
        "reason": "Fico score is very low",
        "created_at": "2019-05-02T07:57:59.705578",
        "decline_code": "fico_too_low",
        "leaf_node_id": 5,
        "decision_type": "credit",
        "triggers_noaa": true,
        "general_description": "FICO score is too low"
    }
]
```

For id = 34257, this is the 'dec_reasons' value in JSONB format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 94772,
        "reason": "Lead Fico Threshold is not Greater Than Or Equal To 500",
        "created_at": "2019-05-02T07:58:05.988900",
        "decline_code": "fico_too_low",
        "leaf_node_id": 7,
        "decision_type": "credit",
        "triggers_noaa": true,
        "general_description": "FICO score is too low"
    },
    {
        "id": 94771,
        "reason": "Fico score is very low",
        "created_at": "2019-05-02T07:58:05.964931",
        "decline_code": "fico_too_low",
        "leaf_node_id": 5,
        "decision_type": "credit",
        "triggers_noaa": true,
        "general_description": "FICO score is too low"
    }
]
```

In each 'dec_reasons' value, there are multiple instances of the 'reason' key. How can I query for the value paired with the 1st instance of 'reason' in each 'dec_reasons' value?

If I queried the for the first instance of the 'reason' key, I'd want to see:

```
'Lead Fico Threshold is not Greater Than Or Equal To 500'
```

If I queried the for the second instance of the 'reason' key, I'd want to see:

```
'Fico score is very low'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query within a jsonb structure you can either use `->` to drill down. This fetches the value of `key` in the second entry.

```
# select '[{"key": 10},{"key": 20},{"key": 30}]'::jsonb->1->'key';
 ?column? 
----------
 20
(1 row)
```

Or you can use `#>` to directly query a path.

```
# select '[{"key": 10},{"key": "20"},{"key": 30}]'::jsonb#>'{1,"key"}';
 ?column? 
----------
 "20"
(1 row)
```

See [json and jsonb Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) in the Postgres docs.